# Appium scrolling with TouchAction

Tags: appium-android

I am using the below code for scrolling:

There is no error from eclipse but during execution I am getting error as “java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception” at the first line itself. It did not execute the second line. Please help.

Appium version: 1.10.0
Java Client: 6.1.0

TouchAction action = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver.getWebDriver());
action.press(PointOption.point(startx,starty)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(50))).action.moveTo(PointOption.point(startx, endy)).release().perform();

Answer (score 3):

This is my swipe method. It works with versions 6.1.0 and 7.0.0 of Appium.
You can use this codes.

```java
public void swipeWithRatio(int startXRatio, int startYRatio, int endXRatio, int endYRatio, int durationMiliSec) {

    Dimension d = getPhoneSize();
    int height = d.height;
    int width = d.width;

    int swipeStartWidth = (width * startXRatio) / 100;
    int swipeStartHeight = (height * startYRatio) / 100;
    int swipeEndWidth = (width * endXRatio) / 100;
    int swipeEndHeight = (height * endYRatio) / 100;

    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(point(swipeStartWidth, swipeStartHeight))
            .waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(durationMiliSec)))
            .moveTo(point(swipeEndWidth, swipeEndHeight))
            .release()
            .perform();
}

// Swipe from up to down example
// It starts from 25 percent of the screen and continues to 75 percent.
swipeWithRatio(50,25,50,75,2000);

// Swipe from down to up example
// It starts from 75 percent of the screen and continues to 25 percent.
swipeWithRatio(50,75,50,25,2000);
```